# how to calculate button width before addView

Tags: android, android-layout

I adding buttons into Horizonatal linearlayout programally, and I want know this button width before layout.

It's because　if buttons's total width over LinearLayout width, App create new LinearLayout below old LinearLayout.

button has 1byte char and multibyte char.

therefore,case of button width when button has only 1byte char, case of button width when button has only multibyte, button width is difference.

```
public void draw() {
　　　　　　　　　width = 320;//screen width
        Button btn;
        int i;
        int twidth = 0;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        lparams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        buttonParams.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);


    for (i = -1; +i < size(); i++) {
        LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(context);
        layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        addView(layout2, lparams);
        twidth = 0;

        while (twidth < width && i + 1 < size()) {
            btn = new Button(context);
            btn.setText(element.get(i + 1).tagName);
            btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            btn.setMaxLines(1);
            btn.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
            twidth += btn.getTextSize() * btn.length() + 10;

            if (twidth >= width) {
                i--;
                break;
            } else {
                btn.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
                btn.setClickable(true);
                btn.setId(element.get(i + 1).tagId);
                layout2.addView(btn, buttonParams);
                i++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

is there solution?